# Why is my Spyder Project no longer working? using scrapy crawl

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Last year i worked on a spyder project and at that point, when we stopped working on the project everything ran and returned results, but we paused the project and now we are looking to start looking at working on it again and now the project isnt working.

Im using Spyder3.6 within Anaconda with scrapy. 
Its a web scraping project. When i try and execute the command scrapy crawl DSG within the IPython Console in spyder, i get a invalid syntax

```
    scrapy check DSG2
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But this was not touched or changed, i simply opened the project and typed the command to make sure everything was working.. and nothing.

What could have happened? What can i check to help me get back to a working state and so we can move forward.

Comment: If i run the file from the anaconda prompt it runs, but i need to be able to test within spyder so i can see what is being returned, when i debug the file, i never see my variables and no break points are hit, i can step into and run current line and nothing

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue to be you cant call scrapy crawl spider from the Iphython console.
Ran it from the command prompt and runs great..